# How does a kafka producer know which are the available brokers from zookeeper?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-producer-api

I have set up a 3 node kafka cluster. I want to know which are the brokers available for a producer client. Is there any command to list down the brokers connected to a zookeeper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the broker list via ZooKeeper by iterating over the broker ids in */brokers/ids* and then fetching the broker info from these ids:

```
ZooKeeper zk = new ZooKeeper("localhost:2181", 10000, null);
List<String> ids = zk.getChildren("/brokers/ids", false);

for (String id : ids) {
   String brokerInfo = new String(zk.getData("/brokers/ids/" + id, false, null));
   System.out.println(id + ": " + brokerInfo);
}
```

Comment: Note: this approach is only supported for backwards compatibility for older clients and does not work for servers configured with security such as SASL_SSL. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3948 The newer approach is to parse and process the endpoints, which include the hostname and port number e.g. "endpoints":["SASL_SSL://kafka01:9093"], and "endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092"],